# How to check that NodeJS script is running on Nginx server

Tags: node.js, nginx, express

I'm trying to configure nodejs + nginx. I've installed nginx and created one express app. I've configured almost everything with the bless of google and gist, and after doing all these things I want make sure that node script is running on nginx. I'm asking such because I started my node server by saying "node app.js" and I've defined my ip add in nginx conf file ( /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default ). Again node is running server and nginx is also a server how come both work together ?

Comment: Can you put your nginx server config?

Comment: I'm following this [tutorial] (http://www.miguelmota.com/blog/nodejs-and-ngnix-on-ubuntu/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using ngnix just for proxying and caching the static files and setting the approprite expire headers.. but the files are served from Express server itself.

> Again node is running server and nginx is also a server how come both work together ?

Yes they both are **web** servers which can receive and interpret the HTTP requests, In this case your requests are handled by Nodejs and nginx is acting as a just proxy server.

Note:

If you want to serve the static files from nginx, you need to set the [root](http://nginx.org/en/docs/beginners_guide.html#static) inside your location config.

Answer (score 1):

nginx is another server which should stay before node server. Node should generate all dynamic content and nginx will serve static files.

So Yes they are separate servers and scripts are run by node.

Comment: But how do I identify that my static content is loaded by nginx only ?